# How to limit the visible items of dropdownlist, which is populated by DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropdownList ASP control`, which is populating by `DataSet`.

I am using `.net 3.5, c#.`

To control the height of DropDownList, i am using the following code and it is working.

```
<asp:DropDownList size="1"
            onMouseOver="this.size=10;"             
            onMouseOut="this.size=1;"
            style="display:none; position:absolute; width:150px;" 
            runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**But it is flickering** when clicking on it, means first it shows all values and again resized for 10, provided length of the control.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I got the correct answer. 
Following code is working properly for me.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" width="100px" onclick="this.size=1;" onMouseOver="this.size=10;" onMouseOut="this.size=1;" style="position:absolute;" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Using `position:absolute;` and `this.size`, i am able to manage the # of items (10 visible).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the ASP.NET dropdown list server control - why not just utilize the **height** property?  Or use Css to control the **height**?

Comment: Thanks Kris, But Height will convert dropdown control as listbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
comboBox1.DropDownHeight = comboBox1.ItemHeight * no of item to display;
```

Comment: husnain, i have updated the question for more clarity. I am unable to find out the property DropDownHeight, if it is an example to calculate the height then height is not an issue, actual issue is flickering.